# Java 2 dim array class

Tags: java, arraylist

I am trying to create a class that creates a defined 2d arraylist and has methods for adding objects and removing objects given x/y. There is going to be another class that will be adding and removing objects, and checking if a space is open. I found an example, but it seem too complicated for my needs, and I don't want to copy their work because I would like to learn something. I don't have experience working with ArrayList, but I've read the Java Docs and understand the gist of it. Here's a link to the example that I was looking at (it's the first post): http://www.javaprogrammingforums.com/java-programming-tutorials/696-multi-dimension-arraylist-example.html

My understanding of a 2D Array list is that it's just an ArrayList that references another ArrayList. Like I said before, I just want a class that handles all the messy stuff and adding and removing objects. Here's what I have; I feel like it's completely wrong because when I try to add a list to another list I get an error saying "Cannot invoke get(int) on the primitive type int". If someone could help me get on the right track I would very much appreciate it. Here's what I have so far:

```
public class BoardMap { 
    private int numOfCols;
    private int numOfRows;`

    private ArrayList<GameObject> cols = new ArrayList<GameObject>(numOfCols);
    private ArrayList<GameObject> rows = new ArrayList<GameObject>(numOfRows);

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    BoardMap(int cols, int rows){
        numOfCols = cols;
        numOfRows = rows;

        for(int i = 0; i < numOfCols; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < numOfRows; j++){
                ((List<GameObject>) cols.get(i)).add(rows.get(j));
            }
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public void addObject(GameObject o, int x, int y){
        ((List<GameObject>) cols.get(x)).add(y, o);
    }

    public void removeObject(GameObject o, int x, int y){

    }

    public boolean occupiedSpace(int x, int y){
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A board can be seen as a list of rows, where each row is a list of cells. Your code uses two lists of cells. It should instead use a single list of lists of cells:

```
List<List<GameObject>> board = new ArrayList<>();

List<GameObject> firstRow = new ArrayList<>();
firstRow.add(new GameObject()); // first cell of first row
firstRow.add(new GameObject()); // second cell of first row
...
board.add(firstRow);

List<GameObject> secondRow = new ArrayList<>();
secondRow.add(new GameObject()); // first cell of second row
secondRow.add(new GameObject()); // second cell of second row
...
board.add(secondRow);
...
```

Of course, you can do all these steps using nested loops:

```
List<List<GameObject>> board = new ArrayList<>();
for (int r = 0; r < rowCount; r++) {
    List<GameObject> row = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int c = 0; c < columnCount; c++) {
        GameObject cell = new GameObject();
        row.add(cell);
    }
    board.add(row);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could load up some default values into a 2-d ArrayList:

```
public class Game {
   private static List<List<Integer>> gameboard = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       gameboard = Arrays.asList(Arrays.asList(1,1,1,1,1),
                Arrays.asList(1,1,1,1,1),
                Arrays.asList(1,1,1,1,1),
                Arrays.asList(1,1,1,1,1),
                Arrays.asList(1,1,1,1,1));
       printBoard();
       incCell(2,2);
       System.out.println();
       printBoard();
   }

   public static void incCell(Integer row, Integer col) {
       gameboard.get(row).set(col, gameboard.get(row).get(col)+1);
   }

   public static void printBoard() {
       for(List<Integer> row: gameboard) {
           for(Integer cell:row) {
         System.out.print(cell);
     }
           System.out.println();
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your board is a rectangle with a fixed size it might be simpler to use a single array to represent it rather than a list of lists.

```
private GameObject[] board;

BoardMap(int cols, int rows){
    numOfCols = cols;
    numOfRows = rows;
    board = new GameObject[cols*rows];
}
```

Then to access a specific cell you would do something like this:

```
public void setObject(GameObject o, int x, int y){
    board[x+y*numOfCols] = o ;
}
```